# C++ pointers: stack for an array was corrupted

Tags: c++, pointers

The problem I want to solve with next code is to rotate the integer array of some size to a certain number shift. 
For instance, for

```
int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5}
```

where `size =5`, for `shift = 2` the result must be

```
{3,4,5,1,2}
```

This is my function

```
void rotate(int a[], int size, int shift)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < shift%size; ++i) {
        int *buffer = &a[0];
        a = &a[1];
        int l = *buffer;
        a[size - 1] = l;
    }
}
```

The output is right, but there is a runtime exception

```
Stack around the variable 'a' was corrupted
```

The problem is definitely in

```
a[size - 1] = l;
```

but I can't understand, what exactly is wrong.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Just so you know, this already exists: `std::rotate`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`a = &a[1];` is shifting the pointer `a` by 1.

So `a[-1]` to `a[3]` inclusive are now the range of valid indices: `a[size - 1]` violates that.

I'd advise against changing `a` in this way.

Answer (score 0):

As Bathsheba already has stated, `a = &a[1];` (which has exactly the same effect as `++a;` or `a++;`) moves the pointer with the effect that the assignment `a[size - 1] = l;` writes to the memory right next to the array. It depends on the code from which `rotate` is being called whether or not an error occurs. I have just run `rotate` together with a suitable `main` without error message (neither during compilation nor at runtime).

But `rotate` impossibly produces the right output. It does not at all rotate anything, but simply writes parts of the array into memory right next to the array. Is just seems as if there were something rotated, when there is sufficient free memory right to the array (otherwise the data there is overwritten) and when you change the startadress of the array also in the code which calls `rotate`.

To better understand what the program does, I have replaced some statements with such with exactly the same effect:

```
void rotate(int a[], int size, int shift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shift%size; ++i) {
        // buffer was superfluous
        ++a;
        // l was superfluous
        a[size - 1] = a[-1];
    }
}
```

The following also has exactly the same effect as your program:

```
void rotate(int a[], int size, int shift) {
    for (int i = 0; i < shift%size; ++i) {
        a[size + i] = a[i];
    }
}
```

Now you can easily see, that the algorithm has to be changed in order to work as demanded.

Comment: Your code moves array in memory, without pushing the first numbers of array into its end. So you have same line of numbers on input and output while by "a[size - 1] = l;" I rotate line a bit, adding previously first numbers to the end of array. But I am agree, this additional variable "L" was not really needed and the solution is not strictly correct.

Comment: I have just rewritten your code to help you understand it better. This is **not at all** a solution of the problem. The point is: Your code (as posted in the question above) **does exactly the same** as the ones in my answer. This just cannot easily be seen as you move the pointer `a` in the loop.